# How to access a svc exposed via ClusterIP from another svc exposed to internet via NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am running two spring boot apps deployed in minikube cluster and exposed as services.
`svc-one` is exposed via NodePort, and I am able to hit the controller in browser by fetching the URL via command `minikube service svc-one --url`.

Now I am trying to access an api written in `svc-two` from svc-one. svc-two is exposed via ClusterIp and I am accessing it via the URL `http://svc-two.default.svc.cluter.local:port`.

But I am getting connection refused error. Is it possible to do in Minikube? Want to confirm if I am making any basic mistake before debugging my service and deployment yaml.

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

ClusterIP are not accessible from outisde your Kubernetes cluster.

So, what you can do is:

- turning the clusterIP into NodePort as well, like svc-one
- add an Ingress to connect to the clusterIP, specifying the svc-two service and port. In this case you access using the url associated to the Ingress
- forward the request with Kubectl (kubectl port-forward <internal_port> <external_port>)

Please, take a look of the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).